# Can I turn off this linking behaviour with EF Code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Not sure if im mis-understanding how EF Code first works or have set it up wrong. I have created a POCO of Charts which has many ChartResults. Simple one to many.

When I do

```
Chart myChart = new Chart();
myChart.ChartResults.Add(new ChartResult(){Pos=1});
myChart.ChartResults.Add(new ChartResult(){Pos=2});
context.Charts.Add(myChart);
context.Save();
```

I get a chart added, and then it tears through all of the chart results and adds that to the database too. This is very clever im sure but the problem is on the chartResults sometimes I want to add and sometimes I want to simply update the reference. But how do I achieve this without:

```
1) going through each Chart and adding it to a new object that is unlinked
2) then going through each ChartResult and explicitely deciding what to do/not do?
```

Comment: You dont have to add myChart to the context and you dont have to save it immediately either.  This allow you to manipulate the POCO in any way you want until you are ready to write to the database.  In the sample above, however, EF is doing just as you asked.

Comment: @HughJones the chart instance will need to be added, at some point, to the context and a call to `SaveChanges()` is required if you want to commit those changes to the database.

Comment: @Jason - of course, but if you want to manipulate the POCOs you can defer the db write until you are ready. That was my point.

Comment: yes, i assumed that went without saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know which `chartresults` to add and which to update then you can load the `chart` and add all the new `chartresult` instances. then you can query for the existing `chartresults` and update them individually.

Or you can loop through the `chartresults` and determine if the entity needs to be added or updated.

BTW: this is irrelevant if EF was mapped via EDMX or code first. this is simply how you interact with the entities, not how to map the entities.

Comment: so your basically saying that the way I am thinking I have to do it is actually the way I have to do it then? I.e. adding a route node to the context and calling .SaveChanges() will create all the children entities...?...

Comment: `SaveChanges()` will commit all the changes to the entities associated with the `dbcontext`.

Comment: right right, well i better try and find a clean way of going through and doing it peice meal! Thanks!....